WPF MVVM ComboBox SelectedItem returns previous item
I have an MVVM-bound ComboBox
<ComboBox x:Name="CBRootPathComboBox"
  ItemsSource="{Binding RootPathComboBoxItems, Mode=OneTime}" 
  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRootPathComboBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction 
          Command="{Binding RootPathComboBoxItemSelectionChangedCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CBRootPathComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>

the Interaction comes from the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf nuget.
Upon SelectionChanged I expected an ICommand with the currently selected item in the list.
In the ViewModel I set the SelectedItem at some point in the code.
I set it in the ViewModel from "Item2" to "Item1" using the ViewModel property.
The chain of calls is then like this:
1. set the property to "Item1"
2. Raise INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event
3. .Net internals calls property getter, it returns "Item1"
4. ICommand call contains "Item2" in parameter. Expected: "Item1"

ViewModel property:
private RootPathItem _selectedRootPathComboBoxItem;
public RootPathItem SelectedRootPathComboBoxItem
{
  get
  {
    Debug.WriteLine($"getting {_selectedRootPathComboBoxItem?.DisplayName ?? "null"}");
    return _selectedRootPathComboBoxItem;
  }
  set
  {
    Debug.WriteLine($"setting {value?.DisplayName ?? "null"}");
    if (_selectedRootPathComboBoxItem != value)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine($"overwriting {_selectedRootPathComboBoxItem?.DisplayName ?? "null"}");
      _selectedRootPathComboBoxItem = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}

XAML: https://github.com/DJDoena/FolderSize/blob/bc0f316a321a5a1a752c4dd12484e2d8684b3700/View/MainWindow.xaml
ViewModel: https://github.com/DJDoena/FolderSize/blob/bc0f316a321a5a1a752c4dd12484e2d8684b3700/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs

The binding to CommandParameter happens before the command is invoked. But why don't you simply execute your command in the setter of SelectedRootPathComboBoxItem as suggested by @EldHasp?

@mm8 see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78443038/wpf-mvvm-combobox-selecteditem-returns-previous-item?noredirect=1#comment138296263_78443569

Several solutions.

No need to use event. Implement the required logic in the VM. In its simplest form for your code it would be like this:

private RootPathItem _selectedRootPathComboBoxItem;
public RootPathItem SelectedRootPathComboBoxItem
{
  get
  {
    Debug.WriteLine($"getting {_selectedRootPathComboBoxItem?.DisplayName ?? "null"}");
    return _selectedRootPathComboBoxItem;
  }
  set
  {
    Debug.WriteLine($"setting {value?.DisplayName ?? "null"}");
    if (_selectedRootPathComboBoxItem != value)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine($"overwriting {_selectedRootPathComboBoxItem?.DisplayName ?? "null"}");
      _selectedRootPathComboBoxItem = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged();

      RootPathComboBoxItemSelectionChangedExecute(value);
    }
  }
}


Retrieve the new selected element from the event argument:

<ComboBox x:Name="CBRootPathComboBox"
  ItemsSource="{Binding RootPathComboBoxItems, Mode=OneTime}" 
  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRootPathComboBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction 
          Command="{Binding RootPathComboBoxItemSelectionChangedCommand}"
          EventArgsParameterPath="AddedItems[0]" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>


You can call a command from an event asynchronously using BeginInvoke, but for this you will have to use i:Interaction.Behaviors instead of i:Interaction.Triggers. What will be somewhat more complicated in the code is InvokeCommandAction vs Behavior.


Maybe I'm lost in the forest because this whole issue started because I basically had it like you show in your code but then I have the problem that despite .NET retrieving the "Item1" from the property, the ComboBox in the UI remains on "Item2". So maybe I'm missing something else in the XAML? I reverted the changes here: https://github.com/DJDoena/FolderSize/commit/708ee789294d7b2a06e9c4af42016517a4535a5e

@DeeJ.Doena I launched a clone of your repository. I was unable to reproduce the error you mentioned. Everything works fine for me.

Here on StackOverflow is a very inconvenient format for communicating on broad topics. There is no way to properly show codes and images in comments. This is only possible in replies. I dare to suggest that you create a topis on a Russian resource, but there are no claims to the English language there. https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/
