WPF MVVM ComboBox SelectedItem gets not propagated from ViewModel to View
I have an MVVM-bound ComboBox
<ComboBox
  ItemsSource="{Binding RootPathItems, Mode=OneTime}" 
  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRootPathItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
</ComboBox>

All items in the ComboBox are memory-unique and created upon starting of the window.
When the user changes the selection in the dropdown the ViewModel property setter is called and the correct object is given to the setter. Then I start some synchronous action based upon the selection and then I want to change the selection to the default selection
private RootPathItem _selectedRootPathItem;
public RootPathItem SelectedRootPathItem
{
    get => _selectedRootPathItem;
    set
    {
      if (_selectedRootPathItem != value)
      {
        _selectedRootPathItem = value;          
        this.OnPropertyChanged();          
        SomeAction();
      }
    }
}

... 
//in SomeAction():
this.SelectedRootPathItem = _nothingComboBoxItem;

The .Net internals will call the property getter again and get the _nothingComboBoxItem but the UI will remain on the previously selected item and not switch to the default.
I also tried to bind SelectedIndex with the same effect.
My guess is because I'm still in the property setter callstack when I set a new item that this does not work but I don't actually know what's going wrong here.

With "some synchronous action" you would not be "still in the property setter callstack". Use a timer or a Task for a truly asynchronous action.

Does your ComboBox's ItemsSource contains _nothingComboBoxItem object? If not, ComboBox will be not able to update the field on the View.

And also if you set SelectedRootPathItem property inside the SomeAction method, which is inside the setter, you end up calling SomeAction twice. Set the back field instead  and call OnPropertyChanged(SelectedRootPathItem) to avoid this, unless it was intended.

@Clemens yes it is synchronous. This is also intended

@bazsisz the _nothing is part of the original items, yes. Also the SomeAction has some early return for "nothing"

In order to help you, can you provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@bazsisz https://github.com/DJDoena/FolderSize/tree/708ee789294d7b2a06e9c4af42016517a4535a5e

Well looking through your code base and testing it out, it seems to me that you are right about the "still in the property setter" theory. It seems ComboBox will not update the View, unless you put the this.SelectedRootPathItem = _nothingComboBoxItem line in a task.
And I also saw that you tried to use interaction behaviour to subscribe to the ComboBox's selection changed event, which I consider a much clearer approch, than doing a lot of things in the property setter. What happaned to that idea? I see the xaml code commented out.
I put back the interaction behavior code in xaml (without the CommandParameter), deleted the _rootPathItemSelectionChangedCommand.Execute(null); line in the setter, and it works flawlessly.
Xaml:
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"
              x:Name="CBRootPathComboBox"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RootPathItems, Mode=OneTime}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRootPathItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RootPathItemSelectionChangedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>

And in the MainViewModel just don't execute command:
    public RootPathItem SelectedRootPathItem
    {
        get => _selectedRootPathItem;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedRootPathItem != value)
            {
                _selectedRootPathItem = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

This should work!

I asked about this here ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/78443038/2334520 ) but there the problem was that the CommandParameter binding apparantly happens before the new value was set and so the ItemChanged event carried the old item in its call which also seemed like I did something wrong.

You don't need CommandParameter. Your actual selected item is available under the SelectedRootPathItem property.  I update my answer to show you what i changed. Let me know if it works for you.

If you want the RootNodes to be cleared if the user selects Nothing directly, consider handling Nothing selection in the switch and not in an early return.

thanks, I'll keep it with the command and the ViewModel property. I was just confused that neither obvious approach worked with WPF / MVVM given that it's not exactly a new technology.

yes it does even though it feels like a workaround. But thank you :-)

You can break out of the callstack using the dispatcher or async/await. Just don't do this in the setter itself. You could use an event handler:
public ViewModel()
{
    ...
    this.PropertyChanged += HandleSetValue;
}

private void HandleSetValue(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SelectedRootPathItem))
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            SomeAction);
    }
}

public RootPathItem SelectedRootPathItem
{
    get => _selectedRootPathItem;
    set
    {
        if (_selectedRootPathItem != value)
        {
            _selectedRootPathItem = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

